# JSF 2 on top of Play! Framework

Tags: jsf-2, playframework

Is it possible to use JSF 2.0 (PrimeFaces for example) as view layer for Play Framework? I'd like to combine elastic hot redeployment of Play with easy component driven JSF developement (instead of MVC and template driven GUI design).

I think all I need is -
1. Run FAces Servlet (javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet) and maybe some other servlet
2. Tweak el-resolver in faces-config.xml just like org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver does.

Have anyone did something like this? I'm new in Play Framework. I use JSF + Spring + JPA now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

JSF is fully based on the stateful aspect of Java EE web stack and on the servlet API!
Play is just a full stateless framework and doesn't use servlet API at all!

So the answer is "No you shouldn't use JSF as the view layer of Play". I use "shouldn't" instead of "can't" because everything is possible but it was be really bad thing!

Nevertheless, you really should think about leaving JSF after wanting to leave MVC. If Play! exists, it's not only because of Rails/Django/Symfony are good, it's also because JSF-like frameworks aren't good, efficient and viable solutions for many reasons you can find everywhere on the web or even in your own experience maybe.

I would advise you just to give a try to Play+JPA (or even something else to replace JPA such as Siena) for real. Don't begin by mixing Java EE stuff with it, use Play 100% to see how it performs. If you need to use Spring with Play, there is no problem but it's not required in many cases. You will discover how easy and efficient it is to build apps from the smallest to the biggest enterprise ones. In my experience, since I use Play, I find this framework promises things and keeps them which is very rare in this world!

Have fun!

Comment: "it's also because JSF-like frameworks aren't good, efficient and viable solutions for many reasons you can find everywhere on the web or even in your own experience maybe." That explains why JSF is so popular.

Comment: No this is just an effect of standards making things used by a majority of people, not an effect of its excellence... I don't know anyone using JSF without complaining about it. But you're right, it's quite popular! I don't say it's completely bad but it's not really good and as soon as you have a problem in a JSF tag, you're stuck.

Comment: I see, you're a primefaces guy! I used primefaces, it think it helps a lot to make JSF less painful. Good stuff even if I encountered a few bugs and even if I'm not a JSF supporter ;)

Comment: Thank You for You answer. Actually I used MVC frameworks for some time. For business applications always page-first frameworks were more better for me than mvc. In old PHP times i replaced Cake (RoR PHP port) by Prado (ASP .NET to PHP port).
Now I'm happy JSF 2.0 user (tried Vaadin too) and business application developement was never so easy in UI layer.

Comment: Remember that HTML is not meant for application UI's but for structured hypertext documents. I like to think about UI components (like Swing or Vaadin) not HTML tags. Vaadin is a bit to JS-heavy but JSF2.0 is a reasonable compromise. I agree that JSF 1.0 was a pain in the a**. Many things changed.

I'd probably take a look at Play. It's a great framework, and my first choice for simple website developement. Maybe some other component based, pull-style UI framework will make it fit business-application developement ready for me. Flex + Play! would be perfect!

Comment: I agree that HTML is structured hypertext docs but modern websites are no more only text so we can't focus on this single aspect anymore. JSF2 is acceptable nowadays because there are frameworks like primefaces providing UI objects intensively using stuff like Jquery. But, the way to go to this acceptable state was quite long and I still feel JSF is like a default solution in the Java world because we don't have anything better.

Comment: Play is interesting because it tries to reconsider the holy principle of JEE stateful+servlets with respect to Rails successful stories. The stateless approach is really practical and efficient to build serious sites using robust templating engines. I know by exp that lots of webapps are based on "traditional" JEE/JSF frameworks and they work well. But it's not a reason not to think how to do things better and easier. As a developer, I can also say that, with play, you don't fight against the framework all the time trying to fit it into your needs. It's quite intellectually satisfying ;)

Comment: I used both Play and JSF2/Primefaces and complained about Play way more, so "I don't know anyone using JSF without complaining about it" is not really an argument :) P.S. Play actually doesn't provide anything useful for the 'View' part of MVC except some poor templating engine like JSP/Velocity (Template View pattern), while JSF2 (and libraries based on it) implements quite decent web component framework (Two-Step View pattern). The only competitor of JSF2 in that field may be GWT.

Comment: >`JSF is fully based on the stateful aspect of Java EE web stack` - This is not correct. JSF does not necessarily have to be stateful.

Comment: unfortunately you does not understand what is JSF. when you said JSF are not good it means what Java EE standards are not good, you should know what most of strong systems in the world based in java EE, JSF already 10 years used in production and solve problems which is still exist in many js framework, and they try to copy jsf stack. ebay and amazon one of examples of success using jsf. unfortunately you does not separate front and back end stacks. also with play you cant have repid development, you will have may bugs, also play can be compared fram. like codeigniter, grails.

Answer (score 7):

By default, no this is not possible.

Play does not conform to the J2EE specification, and as such does not implement the Servlet specification.

However, it *may* be possible, with a fair amount of effort. Play developers have already created a ServletWrapper that allows Play to be deployed to standard servlet containers (like JBoss and Tomcat etc), so they have shown that you can integrate with J2EE technology, if you want to spend the time and effort to write your own Plugin that overwrites the default nature of Play.

I wouldn't bother though. Just take a look at the template engine that comes with Play. It is very good, and I have not missed JSPs at all since using Groovy.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JSF2.2+Primefaces and Spring + AKKA framework which is better and faster than play.